# Debugging a custom Gradle plugin started from the tooling API

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am implementing a custom plugin, which I want to run via the Gradle tooling API. [We can take this project as exact baseline](https://github.com/melix/gradle-tapi-demo-artifacts) for my problem.

I essentially want to be able to put a breakpoint inside of the plugin code (in that case the https://github.com/melix/gradle-tapi-demo-artifacts/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/org/gradle/demo/plugin/OutgoingArtifactsModelBuilder.java.)

The actual Gradle plugin is called from a Java file located in another Gradle module. In that case [App.java](https://github.com/melix/gradle-tapi-demo-artifacts/blob/master/inspector/src/main/java/org/gradle/demo/tapi/App.java).

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        GradleConnector connector = GradleConnector.newConnector();
        connector.forProjectDirectory(findProjectPath(args));
        ProjectConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = connector.connect();
            ModelBuilder<OutgoingArtifactsModel> customModelBuilder = connection.model(OutgoingArtifactsModel.class);
            customModelBuilder.withArguments("--init-script", copyInitScript().getAbsolutePath());
            OutgoingArtifactsModel model = customModelBuilder.get();
            for (File artifact : model.getArtifacts()) {
                System.out.println("artifact = " + artifact);
            }
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I cannot find a way to run that Java file and have the breakpoint be hit in the plugin. I understand that I somehow should be launching a remote debug session against the created Gradle deamon but no luck so far.

The `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true` is not supported when running the Java file directly. I also tried to set those flags inside my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` but without success either (The gradle daemon then refuses to run).

The project is a composite build, I am not sure whether that is relevant.

There are a few too many moving pieces over here for me apparently, if someone has some pointers that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make a breakpoint in the plugin's source code being hit when runnning the inspector app by adding `-Dorg.gradle.debug=true` to `withArguments` *and* reducing the Gradle daemon's idle timeout to 1 second to effectively disable it. In total, [this](https://github.com/melix/gradle-tapi-demo-artifacts/compare/master...sschuberth:gradle-tapi-demo-artifacts:debug) works for me.